# Failure obtaining db row lock: No row exists in table QRTZ_LOCKS for lock named: TRIGGER_ACCESS

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to Quartz scheduler and I'm using it with spring ... When I tried to run the XML file that contains Quartz configuration I got an exception stating that:

```
Failure obtaining db row lock: No row exists in table QRTZ_LOCKS for lock named: 
TRIGGER_ACCESS
```

I found that the table QRTZ_LOCKS contains two fields: SCHED_NAME and LOCK_NAME and that I should run the following statements in my database:

```
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('my sched_name', 'TRIGGER_ACCESS'); 
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('my sched_name','JOB_ACCESS'); 
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('my sched_name','CALENDAR_ACCESS'); 
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('my sched_name','STATE_ACCESS'); 
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('my sched_name','MISFIRE_ACCESS');
```

but I don't have a clue what is my sched_name ??

Any idea ??

Comment: Provide your quartz version please.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to run

```
      INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('TRIGGER_ACCESS');
      INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('JOB_ACCESS');
      INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('CALENDAR_ACCESS');
      INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('STATE_ACCESS');
      INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('MISFIRE_ACCESS');
```

That worked for me actually. Stopped the error at least.

Comment: Only this answer is correct. I did as it said and the error like the post title is gone.

Answer (score 2):

That is most likely because you got the table scripts from a newer version of Quartz then you are applying on your application.

If you are using Spring, then you must have Quartz 1.8.x.

[This is where you can find version 1.8.6](http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector.jsp?b=tcdistributions&i=quartz-1.8.6.tar.gz)

**Note: Inside that tar.gz file there is another file without extension. It is a zip file which contains a folder named doc. In there you can find a script for several database engines.**

No manual modifications on data should be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

*my_sched_name* can be retrieved from the table `qrtz_job_details` (sched_name). 
You must have an issue with your quartz configuration/deployement because usually you do not have to insert/update those tables manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but do you have any working examples on Quartz configuration so I could compare it with mine ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get these errors, when you don't have the db tables related to quartz in your db.

Sometimes you may get these errors in migration even though you have the db tables. Please check there are a few changes in db_schema for quartz 1.8 and quart 2.x.

Below is the link for 2.x db scripts, this should perfectly work.

2.x: https://github.com/elventear/quartz-scheduler/blob/master/distribution/src/main/assembly/root/docs/dbTables/tables_mysql.sql

you can check this one too:
https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/database/tables/tables_oracle.sql